# Configure meta tags in Apache tiles definition file?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

How do I create a meta tag in Apache tiles definition file?
For each page I can create a unique title tag but how do I create meta tags?

My title definition is created as follows.

```
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Random Books"></put-attribute>
```

How do I create the meta tag shown below?

```
    <meta name="keywords" content="Novels,Books" />
```

I can't seem to find any examples online that create meta tags.

I was able to accomplish this by adding this to the jsp default page

```
<tiles:insertAttribute name="metaKeyword" ignore="true" />
```

with the following in the Apache tiles defintions file

```
<put-attribute name="metaKeyword" expression="&lt;meta name=&quot;keywords&quot; content=&quot;Novels,Books&quot; /&gt;"></put-attribute>
```

Surely there is a better / more correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps doing it this way is the correct way? It works for me...

```
<put-attribute name="metaKeywords" value="Novels,Books"/>

<meta name="keywords" content="<tiles:insertAttribute name="metaKeywords" ignore="true"/>"/>
```